# Dart orderBy sorting for iterators

Tags: flutter, dart, sorting

The dart .sort() method can't be used as part of the iterator chain.

For example, I can't do the next

```
arr.sort().take(5);
```

In C# they have OrderBy() and OrderByDesc() which can be used to sort by class field and can be used as part of the iterators chain.

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:collection';

final sortedIterator = someIterable.sorted().take(5);
```

You should study both package:async and package:collection.  Lots of bonus functionality maintained by the core Dart team.

Answer (score -1):

Inherently you must know all of the elements of a collection if you want to sort it.  If you have an `Iterable`, you therefore cannot avoid converting it to a `List` first, and once you do that, you can just use `List.sort`.

Since `List.sort()` mutates a `List` without returning it, you also will need to use the cascade operator (`..`) to refer to that mutated `List`:

```dart
var firstFive = (someIterable.toList()..sort()).take(5);
```